# ./~/chartjs-plugin-zoom/dist/chartjs-plugin-zoom.esm.js Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/helpers'

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to use Chart.js zoom in react and I keep getting this error.
Here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "chartjs-plugin-zoom": "^1.2.0",
    "patternomaly": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^2.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [readme](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom#chartjs-plugin-zoom) of the zoom plugin you need to use version 0.7.7 if you want to use it together with Chart.js V2. If you want to use the latest version of zoom you will need to update Chart.js to V3 but this has a lot of [major breaking changes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

`For Chart.js 2.6.0 to 2.9.x support, use version 0.7.7 of this plugin.`

To install a specific version of a lib you can specify it after it like so:

```sh
npm install chartjs-plugin-zoom@0.7.7
```